# Wait for URLSession to finish in a Swift package

Tags: swift, networking, semaphore, urlsession

I'm trying to download a file using URLSession in a Swift Package. This is my code:

```swift
public class Downloader: NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    private lazy var session = URLSession(configuration: .default,
                                          delegate: self,
                                          delegateQueue: nil)
    var semaphore: DispatchSemaphore?

    public func download(fileAt url: URL) {
        semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
        session.downloadTask(with: url).resume()
        semaphore!.wait()
    }

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                           downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                           didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                           totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                           totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        print(Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
    }

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print(location)
        semaphore?.signal()
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I try to use this the application exists immediately without waiting. I know how to set up a semaphore with a closure callback, but this approach does not work. I need to get progress updates so I can't the closure approach.

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a `semaphore` as a property on self. It should be signaled in `didCompleteWithError` and `didFinishDownloadingTo`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my solution with exited from the package with status code, an example for similar situation, first of all you have to use `RunLoop` for wait for the thread.

```
import Foundation

struct Todo: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}

guard let url = URL.init(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1") else {
    fatalError("badURL error")
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        fatalError("error is not nil")
    }
    
    guard let todo = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Todo.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("JSONDecoding error")
    }
            
    print("Todo ",todo)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
    
}.resume()

RunLoop.current.run()
```

The same ideology in `DispatchGroup`, for making thread wait and not kill instantly, use `RunLoop.current.run()` and when your scenario has succeed or failured use exit with `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` or any custom `Int32` variable like below ones.

```
public var EXIT_FAILURE: Int32 { get }
public var EXIT_SUCCESS: Int32 { get }
```